# powershell set-acl for multiple computers provided by a csv

Tags: powershell

I want to change the permission of a folder on multiple pcs, provided in a csv file. the csv doesn't have a header, just the computernames.
problem is, that it does not import the pc names. i can't use a txt file

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath

$file = import-csv -path "$dir\pc.csv"
foreach($pc in $file) {
try {
$acl = get-acl -path "\\$pc\c$\Program Files (x86)\testfolder" 
$new = "users","full","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow" 
$accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $new 
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule) 
$acl | Set-Acl "\\$pc\c$\Program Files (x86)\testfolder"

Write-Output $([string](get-date) + "`t $pc success") | out-file -append -filepath    "$dir\acl_success.log"
}
catch {Write-Output $([string](get-date) + "`t $pc failed") | out-file -append -filepath "$dir\acl_failed.log"
}
}
```

Is it possible to use a invoke-command setting the folder acl using the provided csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say *"i can't use a txt file"*, but what you describe ***IS*** a txt file. No header, just pc names each on its own line.

Also, your script would greatly benefit if you would indent the code.

Try

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath

# set ErrorAction to 'Stop' in order to catch errors
$oldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Get-Content -Path "$dir\pc.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $pc   = $_  # capture this for when we hot the catch block
    $path = "\\$pc\c$\Program Files (x86)\testfolder" 
    try {
        $acl = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $path
        $accessrule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new('Users', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
        $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule) 
        $acl | Set-Acl -LiteralPath $path
        # write to both the console and to file
        ("{0}`t{1} success" -f (Get-Date).ToString(), $pc) | Add-Content -LiteralPath "$dir\acl_success.log" -PassThru
    }
    catch {
        ("{0}`t{1} failed" -f (Get-Date).ToString(), $pc) | Add-Content -LiteralPath "$dir\acl_success.log" -PassThru
    }
}

# restore previous ErrorAction
$ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorAction
```

Using Invoke-Command:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath

$script = {
    # set ErrorAction to 'Stop' in order to catch errors
    $oldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    # you're now running this on the remote pc, so use local path
    $path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\testfolder" 
    try {
        $acl = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $path
        $accessrule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new('Users', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
        $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule) 
        $acl | Set-Acl -LiteralPath $path
        # output the message
        "{0}`t{1} success" -f (Get-Date).ToString(), $env:COMPUTERNAME
    }
    catch {
        "{0}`t{1} failed" -f (Get-Date).ToString(),  $env:COMPUTERNAME
    }
    # restore previous ErrorAction
    $ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorAction
}

$allPCs = @(Get-Content -Path "$dir\pc.csv")  # force it to be an array, evenif just one pc name in the file
# run the scriptblock on the $allPCs array
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $allPCs -ScriptBlock $script

$result | Where-Object { $_ -match 'success' } | Add-Content -Path "$dir\acl_success.log" -PassThru
$result | Where-Object { $_ -match 'failed' }  | Add-Content -Path "$dir\acl_failed.log" -PassThru
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply. in the meantime I had managed it too. I had updated my question in the meantime. is there a way to speed it up by using a invoke command. i failed using the foreach object with the invoke command

Comment: @chkdsk Please see my edit for using `Invoke-Command`. You may need to add the `-Credential` switch there and add the credentials of a domain admin, because you are trying to modify a folder in 'C:\Program Files (x86)', and a normal user is not allowed that.

Comment: thanks for that. its running like a charm. i don't need the credential paramater because i am already running my script as admin. thnak you so much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:
$file = import-csv -path "$dir\pc.csv"

Use:
$file = get-content "$dir\pc.csv"

Comment: i test it with only one pc in the csv but the script isnt finnishing